# How do i make the alarm work?

Tags: android, media-player, alarm

I have this code written but i have no idea how to add the mediaplayer into it. Anyone here could guide me in this ?

```
public class AndroidTimeActivity extends Activity {

    TimePicker myTimePicker;
    Button buttonstartSetDialog;
    TextView textAlarmPrompt;

    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog;

    final static int RQS_1 = 1;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        textAlarmPrompt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.alarmprompt);

        buttonstartSetDialog = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startSetDialog);
        buttonstartSetDialog.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textAlarmPrompt.setText("");
                openTimePickerDialog(false);

            }});

    }


    private void openTimePickerDialog(boolean is24r){
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(
                AndroidTimeActivity.this, 
                onTimeSetListener, 
                calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), 
                calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), 
                is24r);
        timePickerDialog.setTitle("Set Alarm Time");  

        timePickerDialog.show();

    }

    OnTimeSetListener onTimeSetListener
    = new OnTimeSetListener(){

        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

            Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();

            calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
            calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
            calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

            if(calSet.compareTo(calNow) <= 0){
                //Today Set time passed, count to tomorrow
                calSet.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            }

            setAlarm(calSet);
        }};

    private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal){

        textAlarmPrompt.setText(
                "\n\n***\n"
                + "Alarm is set@ " + targetCal.getTime() + "\n"
                + "***\n");

        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

    }
}
```

Comment: In your AlarmReceiver.class, there you can put your MediaPlayer and the sound you want to play!

Comment: Alright thanks Lucifer i will give it a try now.